# Is a date within several date ranges

Tags: excel

I'm trying to put together an excel spreadsheet to show the day-by-day impact of stays by 3rd country citizens in the EU's Schengen area (it's a fairly complex rolling 180 day window). At the moment, I have a column with every day from a start date (so lots of rows) and another where I enter a 1 if there was a stay in a Schengen country for that day. Then other columns calculate when the 180 day period started and how many days have been in Schengen for that day.

It's a bit of a faff having to enter a 1 for every day away. I'd like to have another worksheet where I simply enter the start and end dates of (an arbitrary number of) each stay and then the calculation spreadsheet simply works out if each date falls within a stay or not. Working out whether a date falls within one date range is pretty straightforward, but working out if it falls within several date ranges isn't obvious to me. Any suggestions please?

After a very fair comment, here's a couple of images that hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do (please ignore the colours).

Example of date ranges, but the number of these should be arbitrary:

[image: Example of date ranges, but the number of these should be arbitrary]

The calculated sheet - currently I have to enter the 1s individually whereas I'd like them evaluated from the date ranges:

[image: The calculated sheet - currently I have to enter the 1s individually whereas I'd like them evaluated from the date ranges]

Comment: Plz try to include  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to make your question more specific and attract more focused answers. It sounds on the face of it as though it might just need some countifs but difficult to be sure.

Comment: What is the logic to assign `1` in the second table based on the previous one?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do automatically. At the moment, I have to put a 1 in for each day that's in the Schengen area.